# Include external html into enduro.js

Tags: javascript, html, enduro.js

I have an enduro.js blog based on this tutorial:

https://www.endurojs.com/blog/how-to-make-a-blog-with-endurojs

And I want to add navbar and footer as external `.html` files available on some URL. How can I include some navbar url into following code which is component  "header.hbs":

```
<header>
    <div class="inner">
        <h1><a href="{{global.base_url}}">{{global.site_name}}</a></h1>
        {{#if global.site_description}}
            <p>{{global.site_description}}</p>
        {{/if}}
    </div>

</header>
<nav class="aSiteNav" id="navbarDiv">
    <div class="inner">
        {{#if global.show_archive_link}}
            <a href="/blog/archive/">{{global.archive_link_text}}</a>
        {{/if}}
        {{#navlinks}}
            {{#each this}}
                <a href="/blog/pages/{{this.page_slug}}/">{{this.content.navigation_title}}</a>
            {{/each}}
        {{/navlinks}}
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by including jquery:

```
<header>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
   <script>
      $(function(){
        $("#navbar").load("https://mydomain.xyz/navbar.html");
      });
   </script>  
   <div class="inner" id="navbar">
   </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
<header>
    <iframe id="inlineFrameExample" src="{{url_of_your_header}}"></iframe>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesnt work, I am just getting "Error processing page"

Comment: The iframe tag wasn't closed, now should work. Anyway your solution is also valid.